# How to search for 2 criteria in Row 1 and then search the column directly below that cell for a second criteria to then copy adjacent data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data sheets that are spit out by python that I need to take the data from and transfer over to the reporting data sheets that I have set up. There can be multiple samples, multiple data sheets and there are ~30 compounds for each data file that needs to be transferred, so a LOT of data. We're trying to make it so we don't have to copy and paste all the data to each individual sheet as that would take quite a while for most people. I'm pretty new to coding in general and while I've gotten pretty far with setting up the sheet and getting it ready for the data, I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to really begin to tackle this last step.

I essentially need it to read row 1 to find a cell that contains a specific value (for example a cell that contains a title that contains the following text '_1.D' and 'air blank'), and then once it finds that cell it will search that column for each compound name (compound 1, Compound 2, etc.). Once it finds the row in that column that has that name, it will then need to take the data in that row from the 4 adjacent columns. For example: It finds the first criteria in Row 1 Column A. It then searches Column A and finds that Compound 1 is in Row 3. It will then take columns B3:E3, copy that data, and transfer it to the Compound 1 sheet I have made (named EXACTLY the same as the column A cell) into a row that is named the same as the search criteria (in this case Air Blank).

This is my first time using Stack Overflow so I'm not sure if there's a way to link excel sheets but I have an example sheet made. I can't give actual data so it's nonsense data but is enough to get an idea of what needs to be done.

I currently have code set up to be able to input which data sheet from python you want to extract data from (for example a sheet called '121314'), and it then will go to that sheet to be able to begin searching for the data it needs to move. But the actual 'begin searching' part I am just completely lost on.

I have a function present in my module as well as the actual sub that I will post below:

```
Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

```
Sub FindAndAddData()

Dim rs As Worksheet
Dim shname As String

Do Until WorksheetExists(shname)
shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")

If StrPtr(shname) = 0 Then
MsgBox ("User Cancelled!")
Exit Sub

Else
If Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation

End If

Loop

Sheets(shname).Select

End Sub
```

There may totally be a better way to do this, or maybe I'm asking for too much from Excel. But I'm really hoping there's a way to get this to work. I've been working on the coding and formatting of this sheet for a good month and a half at this point and would be greatly disappointed if I can't manage to get this to work.

Edit:
Here's screenshots to show an example of what the python spit out looks like and what the reporting sheet would look like.

[Python Spit out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXRrs.png)

[Example Reporting Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PGpi.png)

Comment: Can't pretend I fully understand what you're doing - a screenshot might help - but the `Find` method might be a place to start.

Comment: I went ahead and added screenshots of the two example sheets.

Comment: This will be a pretty complex process overall and there are a likely a lot of business rules linked to your analyses which no-one here will be familiar with...

Comment: What does the Python program do?  Is it reading some other format of output and creating the Excel files as an intermediate?

Comment: that would be correct, it's taking data from an instrument (a Gas chromatography instrument) and converting the data to an excel file to report data.

Comment: re "asking for too much from Excel"  - what you want is for sure possible in Excel/VBA, but it's going to be a bit of work.  This is in my ballpark though - let me know if you could share some actual sample data offline and I'll post my email.  I will take a look if I get some free time.

Comment: Oh yeah I definitely knew it was going to be a lot of work, but I want to be able to learn and get this working the best it can be! I 100% can share some actual sample data offline!

Answer (score 0):

I would skip VBA altogether and just use FILTER formulas, along the lines of

=FILTER(DataFromPython!B:E,DataFromPython!A:A="Compound 5")

Or, if you have Compound 5 in cell B2 on the sheet:

=FILTER(DataFromPython!B:E,DataFromPython!A:A=B2)

FILTER is available in Excel 2019, 2021, and 365 so it is likely that you have it.

Otherwise, Power Query would also work, as would a whole slew of different formulas....

Comment: The problem with using something like that is that it assumes the same type of sample (Air blank, standard, sample, etc) is going to be in the exact same place every time. It's not. The datasets that python spits out are variable as we run different sequences each time. So I need something that's going to be able to search for specific criteria for that specific data set/sequence.

Comment: Then, perhaps, something like =LET(col,MATCH(B2,DataFromPython!1:1,FALSE),d,OFFSET(DataFromPython!A1,0,col-1,100000,5),DROP(FILTER(d,TAKE(d,,1)=B2),,1))

Answer (score 0):

Then try something like this, if 'air blank' is always in the first row or DataFromPython

=LET(col,MATCH("*air blank",DataFromPython!1:1,FALSE), d,OFFSET(DataFromPython!A1,0,col-1,100000,5),DROP(FILTER(d,TAKE(d,,1)=B2),,1))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).